# HQL Query with Select, Order and Desc doesn't work

Tags: mysql, hql

My Hibernate query does not return a result. What is wrong with it?

```
long senderId=42461335;
long recipientId=40524960;
Query query = session.createQuery("Select im.ReadTime From InternalMessage im WHERE im.SenderId=:senderId AND im.RecipientId=:recipientId ORDER BY im.Id DESC");
query.setLong("senderId", senderId);
query.setLong("recipientId", recipientId);
query.setMaxResults(1);
InternalMessage result = HibernateQueryUtil.uniqueResult(query, session);
```

The MySQL version of my query is:

```
SELECT read_time FROM InternalMessage WHERE sender_id="42461335" AND recipient_id="40524960" ORDER BY sent_time DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: In your SQL query you manage senderId and recipientId as String, in HQL as long. Which is the data type on DB of two fields?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and if it does not work do not forget to post console log or the error message in you log file.

```
  String hql = "Select im.ReadTime From InternalMessage im WHERE im.SenderId=:senderId AND im.RecipientId=:recipientId ORDER BY im.Id DESC";
    Query q = session.createQuery(hql);
    q = session.createQuery(hql);
```